# Where do those beans returned by Spring getBean method come from?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aop

Could you please list all possible sources of `getBean`?

BTW, If I just write `context.getBean(SomeInterface.class)`, can I get the implementation of the interface class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come from the Spring application context (which is what you are calling the `getBean` method on).

Spring has this concept of an application context, which is an object that contains things such as all the beans managed by Spring.

You put beans in the application context by configuring them in a Spring XML configuration file or by annotating classes with annotations such as `@Component`, `@Service` etc. and then letting Spring find them by scanning packages for those classes.

If you write `context.getBean(SomeInterface.class)` and there is a Spring bean that implements that interface, then that method call will return the bean that implements the interface.

These are basic concepts of the Spring framework. See [chapter 5, The IoC Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans) in the Spring documentation for a detailed explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the ApplicationContext class hierarchy, you will find that all spring Application Context file are child of org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader class.

What DefaultResourceLoader does is it get the current thread context class loader(if none is provided). So we can understand that all application context file first load the classes defined. Application Context load all the beans defined in xml file, marked using @Bean annotation or other available spring annotations. Once the context scan through the annotation and/ or xml and load all the beans in the class loader. Context first create the dependencies and inject them in dependent.

To get context.getBean(SomeInterface.class), please refer below documentation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean(java.lang.Class)

As per my understanding of documentation, you shall get the bean if exact one implementation bean class is defined.